# Creation of .dll file from .C file

Tags: dll

I want to know which compiler I can use to create a .dll file from a .C file.
I cant find any tutorial how to create a .dll file from a C file.
I am new to creating dll files . Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that you want to create a DLL from a .C file. Just to clarify, are you using C (.c file) or C++ (.cpp) to write your code?Also, if you are using C++, are you using Visual Studio?

- If you are using C: National Instruments provides an ANSI C Application Development Environment called LabWindows/CVI which makes building dlls a snap. It has templates for DLLs and you can build them either as stdcall or cdecl dlls. 
  [Building a DLL with LabWindows/CVI 8.5 for use with LabVIEW 8.5](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7251/en/)
- If you are using Visual C++: Look at the link that Al provided earlier.
  [Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx)
- If you aren't using CVI or Visual Studio, then really the best bet is to do a google search for "Create C DLL".

I would suggest if you have .C file go with Eclipse

**EDITED**

[Eclipse Managed Build](http://eclipsebook.in/c-cpp-development/building-code/build-eclipse-managed/)

+

[Shared libraries with Eclipse CDT and cygwin on Windows](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2010/03/03/shared-libraries-with-eclipse-cdt-and-cygwin-on-windows/)

Comment: Hi Aryabhata,

Thank you very much for answering my question in such a short notice.
I am using C file to  write my code.
I dont have LabWindows/CVI but I have the eclipse.

So shall I go for Eclipse for creating DLL for any C code ?

Request you please send me a link where I can find step by step creation of dll libraries for  C code using Eclipse ?

Thanks and Reagards,
Sid

Comment: Thank you very much  Santosh Dhanawad.

Comment: I have eclipse . I was following the steps for creating a DLL library for a C file mentioned in the link http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2010/03/03/shared-libraries-with-eclipse-cdt-and-cygwin-on-windows/   PLEASE HELP

While creating the new project I noticed that Cygwin GCC was missing. So I downloaded Cygwin and installed it on the C drive.
After that in the environment variables I gave the path 
 C:\cygwin\bin  and restarted eclipse but still Cygwin GCC was not shown while creating new C project.